# How to solve the problem of error 503 when Deploy Angular 10 to Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku

English isn't my first language , so please excuse any mistakes.
I'm trying to deploy my angular 10.0.14 app on Heroku.

After setting the project according to the steps, the subordinates have the following error:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlUPQ.png)

===========================
[hreoku build log ]

heroku's build result : "Build succeeded!" 
No obvious error message is seen in the active build log
https://www.evernote.com/l/AgiYqPvwz1tGYqSidTRBJRWDz0W8ufofYow/

===========================
[Failed heroku app link ] 
https://first-angular20200829.herokuapp.com/

========steps start ===================
[Deploy steps ]
A.create +install angular
1.ng new [project name ]
2.cd [project name ]
3.ng s

=========================== 
B.edit [project name ]/ package.json : 
https://github.com/aloo31124/first-angular/blob/master/package.json

```
{
"name": " [project name ]",
...
  "scripts": {      
    "start" : "node server.js",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod",
//Some articles use "postinstall" and some are "heroku-postbuild" . I tried both but it still didn't work.
...
},
"engines": {
    "node": "10.16.0",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  },

"dependencies": {
    ...
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
}
```

===========================

C.install express 
npm install express path --save

check express :

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
}
```

=========================== 
D.Create server.js in the root directory [project name] : 
https://github.com/aloo31124/first-angular/blob/master/server.js 
[project name ]/server.js

```
//Install express server
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/[project name ]'));
app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/[project name]/index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

=========================== 
E. github 
git add . 
git commit -m "xxx" 
git push 
=========================== 
F.Deploy on heroku 
1.Go to heroku homepage 
2.Select "Deploy" tab> "Deployment method" field select GitHub 
3.Press the Deploy button in the "Manual deploy" field

======== steps end ============== 
Thank you for your patience after reading this article,  
and I hope someone can advise me.

=========================== 
ref :   
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVFrTf4VD2o  
https://www.manonglife.com/2019/03/angular-heroku.html

Comment: 503 (Service Unavailable) occurs in your browser console after the app loading or it is not loading at all?

Comment: Try to compile like this, ng build --prod --base-href=.

Comment: From the console in the link, the app doesn’t seem to be loaded into the browser from the beginning.
https://first-angular20200829.herokuapp.com/

Comment: " ng build --prod --base-href=." is not work.

Comment: Your method solved my problem
thank you very much :)